# No packages in any requested group available to install or update When I install the "X Window System"

Tags: centos, yum

I want to install the `X Window System` in my remote CentOS 7.2(I use ssh login to the server) , but get bellow error:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum groupinstall "X Window System" 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.01link.hk
 * extras: centos.01link.hk
 * updates: centos.01link.hk
Maybe run: yum groups mark install (see man yum)
No packages in any requested group available to install or update
```

Why I can not install the `X Window System`?

---

**EDIT-01**

I read [this post](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1262603#comment-867063).

seems many people have this issue, and there is no solution there.

---

**EDIT-02**

I use bellow command for listing the group hidden.

```
# yum group list hidden
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.01link.hk
 * extras: centos.01link.hk
 * updates: centos.01link.hk
Installed Environment Groups:
   GNOME Desktop
Available Environment Groups:
   Minimal Install
   Compute Node
   Infrastructure Server
   File and Print Server
   Basic Web Server
   Virtualization Host
   Server with GUI
   KDE Plasma Workspaces
   Development and Creative Workstation
Installed Groups:
   Base
   Common NetworkManager submodules
   Core
   Desktop Debugging and Performance Tools
   Development Tools
   Dial-up Networking Support
   Directory Client
   E-mail Server
   Fonts
   Graphical Administration Tools
   Guest Agents
   Guest Desktop Agents
   Hardware Monitoring Utilities
   Hyper-v platform specific packages
   Input Methods
   Internet Applications
   Internet Browser
   Java Platform
   KVM platform specific packages
   Legacy UNIX Compatibility
   Legacy X Window System Compatibility
   Multimedia
   Network File System Client
   Network Infrastructure Server
   Networking Tools
   Performance Tools
   Perl Support
   Print Server
   Printing Client
   Remote Desktop Clients
   Security Tools
   System Administration Tools
   VMware platform specific packages
   Virtualization Client
   Virtualization Hypervisor
   X Window System
Available Groups:
   Additional Development
   Anaconda Tools
   Backup Client
   Backup Server
   CentOS Linux Client product core
   CentOS Linux ComputeNode product core
   CentOS Linux Server product core
   CentOS Linux Workstation product core
   Compatibility Libraries
   Conflicts (Client)
   Conflicts (ComputeNode)
   Conflicts (Server)
   Conflicts (Workstation)
   Console Internet Tools
   DNS Name Server
   Debugging Tools
   Directory Server
   Emacs
   FTP Server
   File and Storage Server
   GNOME
   GNOME Applications
   Graphics Creation Tools
   High Availability
   Identity Management Server
   Infiniband Support
   KDE
   KDE Applications
   KDE Multimedia Support
   Large Systems Performance
   Load Balancer
   Mainframe Access
   MariaDB Database Client
   MariaDB Database Server
   Office Suite and Productivity
   PHP Support
   Perl for Web
   Platform Development
   PostgreSQL Database Client
   PostgreSQL Database Server
   Python
   Remote Management for Linux
   Resilient Storage
   Ruby Support
   Scientific Support
   Smart Card Support
   System Management
   Technical Writing
   Virtualization Platform
   Virtualization Tools
   Web Server
   Web Servlet Engine
Done
```

Comment: please show the output of command `yum group list hidden`

Comment: But `X Window System` is already installed, so you cannot install it one more time. Do you have a problem with Graphical Environment?